# How do I prevent the JS onclick event in hyperlinks that are loaded in dynamically from firing?

Tags: jquery, load, preventdefault

How do I prevent the JS onclick event in hyperlinks that are loaded in dynamically from firing? I want to open all links in a particular div on the same page rather than opening a separate window. Here's the code I tried. When I click a link from the loaded content, it opens in a new window. I think the issue is with the built in "onclick" attribute in the  tag. How do I neutralize that so that all links open in the same div?

```
$(document).on('click', "a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get url
    // url looks like this:    <A onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" onfocus=OnLink(this)      href="...linkAppearsHere"target=_self>Course</A>
    var thisURL = $(this).attr('href') + ' #onetIDListForm';
    var thisTitle = $(this).html();
    $('#itemPage').load(thisURL);
    $('#itemPageHeading').html(thisTitle);
});
```

Comment: you can use <p></p> or any other suitable tag instead of <a></a> one... this should stop it to behave like a link, but you can still wire a click event to it ...

Comment: But how do I do that BEFORE it fires?

Answer (score 0):

By default the links should open in the current browser window. You can remove the onclick and any target attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('a').removeAttr('onclick').removeAttr('target'); });
```

Your click handler with `event.preventDefault();` is actually the 2nd click handler, therefore the click event is being processed by your handler as well as the onclick attribute. You can try overriding the function GoToLink so that is does nothing, or removing the onclick attributes on the elements.

To explain a bit further, you can have multiple click handlers. If you open your console and do the following:

```
var links = $('a');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    links.on('click', function() { alert('Clicked'); });
}
```

You'll see 10 alerts for every click. You can remove click handlers similarly with:

```
links.off('click');
```

However, this won't remove the onclick attribute which is embedded into the DOM. You'll need to call removeAttr('onclick') to do so.

Comment: @butaqi Well, `$(document).on` will add a listener that is triggered by whichever event you specify, i.e. 'click'. Presumably, we want to remove the attributes before the user has a chance to trigger the click, so you'd want to execute the code whenever the elements are loaded into the DOM.

`$(document).ready` will execute on page load. But if you have AJAX requests that are inserting these elements dynamically into your DOM, you'll want to run the attribute removal code after the DOM injection, i.e. in the success callback of your AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks!! I added code to neutralize onclick inside the callback of the on event. It works!

Comment: Nice, might want to add it to the callback of your jQuery load

Comment: That's what I did. Now the only problem is when I click to edit the form or create a new record in the form, I don't see all the dropdowns and combox boxes that are in the original page. Does the load method leave somethings out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you isolate the issue into a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output)